# Using cProfile results with KCacheGrind

Tags: python, profiling, kcachegrind, cprofile

I'm using cProfile to profile my Python program. Based upon [this talk](http://blip.tv/file/1957086/) I was under the impression that KCacheGrind could parse and display the output from cProfile.

However, when I go to import the file, KCacheGrind just displays an 'Unknown File Format' error in the status bar and sits there displaying nothing.

Is there something special I need to do before my profiling stats are compatible with KCacheGrind?

```
...
if profile:
    import cProfile

    profileFileName = 'Profiles/pythonray_' + time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S') + '.profile'

    profile = cProfile.Profile()
    profile.run('pilImage = camera.render(scene, samplePattern)')

    profile.dump_stats(profileFileName)
    profile.print_stats()
else:            
    pilImage = camera.render(scene, samplePattern)
...
```

**Package Versions**

- KCacheGrind 4.3.1
- Python 2.6.2

Comment: Just curious, can anyone point me to the talk linked here? It seems to be broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done using an external module called [lscallproftree](http://www.gnome.org/~johan/lsprofcalltree.py)

This article explains how: [CherryPy - CacheGrind](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/Cachegrind)

With my resulting code looking like so:

```
...
if profile:
    import cProfile
    import lsprofcalltree

    profileFileName = 'Profiles/pythonray_' + time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S') + '.profile'

    profile = cProfile.Profile()
    profile.run('pilImage = camera.render(scene, samplePattern)')

    kProfile = lsprofcalltree.KCacheGrind(profile)

    kFile = open (profileFileName, 'w+')
    kProfile.output(kFile)
    kFile.close()

    profile.print_stats()    
else:            
    pilImage = camera.render(scene, samplePattern)
...
```

If anyone knows a way to do this that doesn't require an external (ie. not shipped with Python) module, I'd still be very interested to hear about it.

Answer (score 96):

With cProfile you can also profile existing programs, without making any separate profiling script. Just run program with profiler

```
python -m cProfile -o profile_data.pyprof script_to_profile.py
```

and open profile data in kcachegrind with pyprof2calltree, whose -k switch automatically opens data in kcachegrind

```
pyprof2calltree -i profile_data.pyprof -k
```

For example profiling whole paster server and webapp would be done like this

```
python -m cProfile -o pyprof.out `which paster` serve development.ini
```

pyprof2calltree can be installed with easy_install.

Comment: Unrelated to the topic I have to add that for "paster" it's a lot better to use repoze.profiler filter which can write directly cachegrind format and knows how to limit profiling just to webapp code.

Comment: Side note: on Debian-based systems, the cleanest way to add any python easy_install module as a package is: `sudo apt-get install python-stdeb` then `pypi-install pyprof2calltree`.

Comment: On the Mac you can use `qcachegrind` instead. `pip install pyprof2calltree && brew install qcachegrind`, then `pyprof2calltree -i profile_data.pyprof && qcachegrind profile_data.pyprof.log`.

Comment: @AlexanderLjungberg, you should add `brew install graphviz`

Answer (score 17):

You could use [`profilestats.profile`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/profilestats/) decorator (`$ pip install profilestats`) -- a simple wrapper for [pyprof2calltree](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyprof2calltree) module (rebranding of `lsprofcalltree.py`):

```
from profilestats import profile

@profile
def func():
    # do something here
```

Script can be run as usual. `profilestats` creates two files: `cachegrind.out.profilestats` and `profilestats.prof` in KCachegrind-compatible and cProfile formats correspondingly.

Answer (score 7):

3 differents ways to profile your code and visualizing results in KCachegrind/Qcachegrind:

## I - CPROFILE

1 - Profile myfunc() from ipython

```
import cProfile
filename = 'filename.prof'
cProfile.run('myfunc()', filename)
```

2 - Convert your file to a usable kcachegrind file in your shell

```
sudo pip install pyprof2calltree
pyprof2calltree -i filename.prof -o callgrind.filename.prof
```

3 - Open callgrind.filename.prof in kcachegrind

## II - EMBEDDED CPROFILE

1 - Profile few lines in your code.

```
import cProfile
filename = 'filename.prof'
pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()
# ... lines to profile ...
pr.disable()
pr.dump_stats(filename)
```

2 - Convert your file to a usable kcachegrind file in your shell

```
sudo pip install pyprof2calltree
pyprof2calltree -i filename.prof -o callgrind.filename.prof
```

3 - Open callgrind.filename.prof in kcachegrind

## III - YAPPI

1 - Profile myfunc() from ipython or from your code

```
import yappi
filename = 'callgrind.filename.prof'
yappi.set_clock_type('cpu')
yappi.start(builtins=True)
myfunc()
stats = yappi.get_func_stats()
stats.save(filename, type='callgrind')
```

2 - Open callgrind.filename.prof in kcachegrind

Answer (score 5):

If what you're actually trying to do is see what parts of your code could be optimized for speed, and you can randomly pause it in the debugger, [this method works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024). It may be surprising, but you don't need very many stackshots.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's always handy to have multiple tools in my toolbox. My reasons for using a profiler were both to confirm my suspicions about where the time was being taken up, and as a chance to become acquainted with the available tools.

I'll probably experiment with both full profiles and stack shots going forward.

Comment: I'm not sure what answer this was meant to be linking to but it looks like the question has been migrated so the anchor's not working any more.

Comment: Looks like the question has been removed from programmers.stackexchange.com. Care to summarize what the linked answer was about?

Comment: @akaihola: Yeah, there's a gremlin lurking. I put in a different link.