# How to find the statistics and execution times of the code in python

Tags: python, statistics, execution-time

I am working on python and came across some concept of finding the statistics and execution time of the code

Suppose i had the following code

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
import timeit


def calculation():
     a = 2
     b = 3
     res = a + b
     return  res

if 'name' == 'main' :
    exec_time = timeit.timeit(calculation)
    print exec_time
```

**result:**

```
0.2561519145965576
```

So from the above code i am able to find the execution time of the code , but how to find the statistics of the code in python ?

Finally my intention is below points

1. How to find the statistics of the code in python
2. How to find the execution time of the entire code in python
3. What actually meant statistics of the code ?

**Edited Code:**

For example i had the above code in the file `test.py`

Now i had run the above file with the command below

```
python -m cProfile test.py
```

**Result :**

```
sh-4.2$ python -m cProfile test.py
         4 function calls in 0.001 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 test.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:105(Timer)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 timeit.py:53(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

So i need something like this when i run the above code, what i am trying is to write this functionality of printing statistics inside the file `test.py` instead of running the file with command `python -m cProfile test.py` from terminal.

At least i want to find the statistics and execution time of the function `calculation()` when the file runs because in real the function calculation has big functionality that performs some operation.

Comment: What do you mean by 'statistics of code'?

Comment: You probably need _profiling_ (this is a keyword for further research). Also look at [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3378953/1258041).

Comment: @chris: Thats what my doubt actually, i dont know why its given down vote, i had doubt about this and approached SO

Comment: I edited my code can anyone look around above ....

Answer (score 4):

It appears what you are asking is how to the programmatic interface for the timeit module.  That is documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#python-interface).  You'll need a sample set to calculate statistics, such min, max, average, etc. from, which means running calculate numerous times through the repeat method of the Timeit class included in the timeit module.

For example:

```
timer = timeit.Timer(calculation)
results = timer.timeit(10000)
```

Comment: Actually we can find execution time by passing the function calucation() inside Timer/timeit right?. Fine but what about statistics like i need all the above result info as i mentioned in the above edited code. That is if we run the file as "python -m cProfile test.py" we willl get the entire output as above(how many function calls etc.,), but i don't want to run the file with this command, instead when i run the file as "python test.py", it should display all the result as above, that is we need to implement the cprofile functionality inside the test.py file

Comment: Yes to your question.  In my example above results contains a list of all 10000 timings.  The first column in the printed output is the total calls, which is 10000 in my example since that is what was passed in.  That second column is total time, which would be the sum of the values in the list, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to use `cProfile` from within the code.  It actually turns out to be quite easy.  `cProfile.Profile` has two undocumented methods, `enable` and `disable`, which can be used to start and stop the profiler.  This means you can easily create a context manager or decorator.  The following recipe implements both of these in one object, and includes a way of processing and printing the output with the `pstat` module.

```
import cProfile, pstats, functools

class profile:

    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        """
        If defined, output is written to *filename*, otherwise it
        is processed using *pstats* and printed to STDOUT.
        """
        self._filename = filename
        self._prof = cProfile.Profile()

    def __enter__(self):
        self._prof.enable()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self._prof.disable()
        if self._filename is not None:
            self._prof.dump_stats(self._filename)
        else:
            stats = pstats.Stats(self._prof)
            self.print_stats(stats)

    def print_stats(self, stats):
        """
        This method processes the stats and prints them.
        """
        stats.strip_dirs().sort_stats('cumulative').print_stats(20)

    def __call__(self, func):
        self._func = func
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with self:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
```

So usage is:

```
@profile()
def calculation():
    a = 2
    b = 3
    res = a + b
    return  res

calculation()
```

or

```
with profile('output_file.pstat'):
    calculation()
```

You can change `print_stats` as necessary to show the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach to finding the aggregation stats of the code. You can find the mean, median, standard deviation, total time spent, and number of times called using this library.

The library is called [codetiming](https://github.com/realpython/codetiming) from realpython.

A sample use case:

```py
from codetiming import Timer
from humanfriendly import format_timespan
from loguru import logger


@Timer(name="my_func", text=lambda secs: f"my_func elapsed time: {format_timespan(secs)}")
def my_func():
    ...

def get_aggregated_timings(cls):
    timed_function = "my_func"
    logger.info(
        f"\n{timed_function} count: {Timer.timers.count(timed_function)}\n"
        f"total: {Timer.timers.total(timed_function)}\n"
        f"max: {Timer.timers.max(timed_function)}\n"
        f"min: {Timer.timers.min(timed_function)}\n"
        f"mean: {Timer.timers.mean(timed_function)}\n"
        f"standard deviation: {Timer.timers.stdev(timed_function)}\n"
        f"median: {Timer.timers.median(timed_function)}\n"
    )
    Timer.timers.clear()  # clears all the timer data
```