# VisualVM equivalent for Python

Tags: python, profiling, visualvm

I was wondering if there is a Python equivalent of Java's VisualVM. The feature that I need is real-time profiling of a running Python interpreter.

A bit of background: a recent change to my code base slowed it down considerably. I would like to find out what my code is doing without having to restart the calculation. The alternative is to stop the interpreter and to restart it with `-m cProfile`, losing a day of CPU time.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Python has a `sys.set_trace` that can be set while the program runs. It should be possible to start profiling while the program runs.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: 
[Is there a visual profiler for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378953/is-there-a-visual-profiler-for-python) and here: [Which Python memory profiler is recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/which-python-memory-profiler-is-recommended)

From what I found, there isn't really an easy way to do memory profiling if your application is more than just a script. Otherwise the easiest is to use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler.