# Treemap visualisation view for Python profiler output?

Tags: python, profiling, visualization, data-visualization

Is there a profiler for Python that can render something like Kcachegrind's Callee map view?

[image: kcachegrind Callee Map View]

Comment: This is freaking cool. I guess you could do something like this by parsing an existing profiler's output and fiddling a bit with `pygame` or any other 2D graphics library. No idea if anyone already did that.

Comment: Yeah, our brain's 'GPU' may be better with percentage visualisations than processing numbers.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896032/ on how to use cProfile with python and kCacheGrind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like it might do what you want

http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/

Comment: This has been replaced by https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/ I think.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Ubuntu (or have access to a host) you can convert the Python [hotshot profiler](http://docs.python.org/library/hotshot.html)'s output into a form that KCachegrind can read.  Check out the `kcachegrind-converters` package [hotshot2calltree command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/hotshot2calltree.1.html).

Here are some pages which reference using it for Python profiling:

- [Profile a script using hotshot and kcachegrind](http://fperez.org/py4science/profiling/pycachegrind.html)
- [Django profiling with hotshot and kcachegrind](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/django-profiling-hotshot-and-kcachegrind/)