# How to install RunSnakeRun on OS X with MacPorts?

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, macports

I've installed the `wxWidgets-3.0` `py27-wxpython-3.0` MacPorts packages. In a clean virtualenv I installed the `wx`, `SquareMap`, and `RunSnakeRun` pip packages. Attempting to run `runsnake` fails as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lhn/.virtualenvs/snake/bin/runsnake32", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('RunSnakeRun==2.0.4', 'gui_scripts', 'runsnake32')()
  File "/Users/lhn/.virtualenvs/snake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 353, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Users/lhn/.virtualenvs/snake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2321, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Users/lhn/.virtualenvs/snake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2048, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/Users/lhn/.virtualenvs/snake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/runsnakerun/runsnake.py", line 14, in <module>
    from squaremap import squaremap
  File "/Users/lhn/.virtualenvs/snake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/squaremap/squaremap.py", line 3, in <module>
    import wx.lib.newevent
ImportError: No module named lib.newevent
```

In IDLE I see teh same import error:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 18 2013, 15:12:51)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
>>> import wx.lib.newevent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lib.newevent
```

Comment: Went with qcachegrind as explained at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3561512/708883 (Macports packages `qcachegrind qt4-mac graphviz`) instead.

Comment: Does importing wx.lib.newevent work in the non-virtualenv Python?