# How can I analyze a file created with pstats.dump_stats(filename) off line?

Tags: python, profiling, analysis, pstats

I have essentially done the following:

```
import cProfile, pstats, StringIO
pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()
# ... my code did something ...
pr.disable()
s = StringIO.StringIO()
sortby = 'cumulative'
ps = pstats.Stats(pr, stream=s).sort_stats(sortby)

ps.dump_stats('stats.dmp')  # dump the stats to a file named stats.dmp
```

So now i have the file named 'stats.dmp' stored offline.

How can i use pstats to analyze this file for human consumption?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's what i found out and the Python program I generated. I tested this with a .dmp file made on linux & analyzed on windows xp. It worked FINE. The Python file is named, "analyze_dmp.py".

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
"""analyze_dmp.py takes the file INFILEPATH [a pstats dump file] Producing OUTFILEPATH [a human readable python profile]
Usage:   analyze_dmp.py INFILEPATH  OUTFILEPATH
Example: analyze_dmp.py stats.dmp   stats.log
"""
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2019 Joe Dorocak  (joeCodeswell at gmail dot com)
# Distributed under the MIT/X11 software license, see the accompanying
# file license.txt or http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# I added the above License by request here are my research links
#    https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18883/311363
#    https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128840/311363
#    https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/10746

import sys, os
import cProfile, pstats, StringIO

def analyze_dmp(myinfilepath='stats.dmp', myoutfilepath='stats.log'):
    out_stream = open(myoutfilepath, 'w')
    ps = pstats.Stats(myinfilepath, stream=out_stream)
    sortby = 'cumulative'

    ps.strip_dirs().sort_stats(sortby).print_stats(.3)  # plink around with this to get the results you need

NUM_ARGS = 2
def main():
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    if len(args) != NUM_ARGS or "-h" in args or "--help" in args:
        print __doc__
        s = raw_input('hit return to quit')
        sys.exit(2)
    analyze_dmp(myinfilepath=args[0], myoutfilepath=args[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The following changes make the code to work in Python 3: (1) first line: python2.7 => python3, (2) remove import: do not import StringIO, (3) add slurs: print(__doc__), (4) rename function: change raw_input(...) to input(...)

Comment: Mind adding a license to this script?

Answer (score 26):

You can try `snakeviz` https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz

It is a browser based graphical viewer for the output of Python’s cProfile module and an alternative to using the standard library pstats module.

```
# to install it with pip
pip install snakeviz

# once installed, you can use snakeviz to view the file
snakeviz /path/to/your/dump/pstat/file
```

Here is a sample image for a visualized pstat file you can dump like above.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`kcachegrind`](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/) if you convert your [`pstats`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-pstats) file with [`pyprof2calltree`](https://pypi.org/project/pyprof2calltree/) beforehand:

```bash
$ pyprof2calltree -i /path/to/your/dump/pstat/file -o /tmp/converted_stats
$ kcachegrind /tmp/converted_stats
```

[image: kcachegrind sample session]

If you are using Debian-based system you can easily install both tools by running:

```bash
$ sudo apt install pyprof2calltree kcachegrind
```

See also related thread: [Using cProfile results with KCacheGrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896032/using-cprofile-results-with-kcachegrind)

Comment: how to install kcachegrind in windows?