# memory consumed by a thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

Here I can get the time take by thread to complete. How can I get the memory consumed by the thread.

```
import threading
import time
class mythread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,i,to):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.h=i
        self.t=to
        self.st=0
        self.end=0
    def run(self):
        self.st =time.time()
        ls=[]
        for i in range(self.t):
            ls.append(i)
            time.sleep(0.002)
        self.end=time.time()
        print "total time taken by {} is {}".format(self.h,self.end-self.st)
thread1=mythread("thread1",10)
thread2=mythread("thread2",20)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

Comment: I want the memory used while running only

Comment: You could use `cprofiler` and pass it to `kcachegrind`. If you don't know what I'm talking about, [read up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561512/929999) on debugging processes and memory analyzation.

Comment: I wonder if you know what you measure, using `time.time()`. It is not the cpu time of the threads, since `time.time()` returns the wall clock time, i.e. the actual time of the system. Since both threads are started more or less in parallel, they will excute at the same time, and you will basically measure their combined time (together with anything else that happens to execute at the CPU at the time). Perhaps you want to look into `time.thread_time()` instead?

Answer (score 6):

(This is a bit of a non-answer I'm afraid, but I'd argue that's due to the nature of the subject matter...)

The notion of thread memory usage is not a well defined one. Threads share their memory. The only truly thread-local memory is its call stack, and unless you do something *seriously* recursive, that's not the interesting part.

The ownership of "normal" memory isn't that simple. Consider this code:

```
import json
import threading
import time

data_dump = {}

class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, name, limit):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.limit = limit
        data_dump[name] = []

    def run(self):
        start = time.monotonic()
        for i in range(self.limit):
            data_dump[self.name].append(str(i))
            time.sleep(0.1)
        end = time.monotonic()
        print("thread wall time: {}s".format(end-start))

t1 = MyThread(name="one", limit=10)
t2 = MyThread(name="two", limit=12)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
del t1
del t2
print(json.dumps(data_dump, indent=4))
```

The output of `data_dump` will show you all the strings appended (and thus, allocated) by the threads. However, at the time of the output (the final `print`), *who* *owns* *the* *memory*? Both threads have gone out of existance, yet it is still accessible and thus not a leak. Threads don't own memory (beyond their call stack); processes do.

Depending on what you want to do with these memory consumption numbers, it might help to use cprofiler as recommended by @Torxed.