# Keys won't register (pygame) - I'm convinced that pygame is straight up broken

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.7

Why does this not work

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

while True:
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if pressed[pygame.K_w]:
                print("w is pressed")
            elif pressed[pygame.K_s]:
                print("s is pressed")
```

I installed pygame and python today. It should theoretically be the latest of both pygame and python. this code has gone through many iterations and none of them have worked. I even tried:

```
print(pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w])
```

and that printed only 0. Even when pressing and holding w. I've tried everything.
I tried using:

```
pygame.event.pump()
```

but that did nothing.

no errors or anything, just nothing happens. it just prints what I type on the screen.

I've never posted on stackoverflow before, so sorry if I did something wrong.

**Edit:**
I altered the code from somewhere from here

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get() :
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN :
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE :
          print ("Space bar pressed down.") #Here you should put you program in the mode associated with the pressed SPACE key
        elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE :
          print ("Escape key pressed down.")
      elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP :
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE :
          print ("Space bar released.")
        elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE :
          print ("Escape key released.") #Time to change the mode again
```

nothing. absolutely nothing.

Comment: `python -m trace --trace script.py`, any signs of something weird happening? You could also run a [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561512/929999) just to check and see if something sticks out.

Answer (score 1):

The state which is returned by [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) is evaluated by [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).

This mans `pygame.event.get()` has to be done first. Note if you would do it in the reverse order, and a key pressed event happens, the the event loop will run, but `pygame.key.get_pressed()` has already has returned the deprecated states. So the state `pressed[pygame.K_w]` and `event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN` will never be fulfilled in the same run of the loop. The will be fulfilled in 2 consecutive runs loops.

Change your code like this, to solve the issue:

```py
events = pygame.event.get()
pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

for event in events:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if pressed[pygame.K_w]:
            print("w is pressed")
        elif pressed[pygame.K_s]:
            print("s is pressed")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't create a screen. I'm uncertain if that matters, but I suspect it does.

Also, you're mixing the "for event in pygame.event.get():" pattern, and the "pygame.key.get_pressed()" pattern.

Comment: "share a screen"?

Comment: Add screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480)) after pygame.init()